# Kubernetes Persistent Volume Claim Indefinitely in Pending State

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I created a PersistentVolume sourced from a Google Compute Engine persistent disk that I already formatted and provision with data. Kubernetes says the PersistentVolume is available.

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: models-1-0-0
  labels:
    name: models-1-0-0
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 200Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  gcePersistentDisk:
    pdName: models-1-0-0
    fsType: ext4
    readOnly: true
```

I then created a PersistentVolumeClaim so that I could attach this volume to multiple pods across multiple nodes. However, kubernetes indefinitely says it is in a pending state.

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: models-1-0-0-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 200Gi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: models-1-0-0
```

Any insights? I feel there may be something wrong with the selector...

Is it even possible to preconfigure a persistent disk with data and have pods across multiple nodes all be able to read from it?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I quickly realized that PersistentVolumeClaim defaults the `storageClassName` field to `standard` when not specified. However, when creating a PersistentVolume, `storageClassName` does not have a default, so the selector doesn't find a match.

The following worked for me:

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: models-1-0-0
  labels:
    name: models-1-0-0
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 200Gi
  storageClassName: standard
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  gcePersistentDisk:
    pdName: models-1-0-0
    fsType: ext4
    readOnly: true
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: models-1-0-0-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 200Gi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: models-1-0-0
```

Comment: run `kubectl describe pvc` to confirm if this is the bug, you'll get `"Cannot bind to requested volume "YOUR_PV_NAME": storageClasseName does not match"`

Comment: had same issue. it's strange that k8 dashboard just stays pending and not report the error !

Comment: +1 Also had this issue on an AWS EC2 cluster setup with kops. To get the PV/PVC connected properly, I had to add `storageClassName: gp2` to both. There are some related docs on [setting a storage class](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/storage-classes.html) for your AWS cluster and [types of EBS volumes available](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumeTypes.html)

For some reason, I wasn't getting the error message noted by @s12chung

Comment: @wronk same worked for me adding `storageClassName: standard` to the pv and pvc in GCP

Answer (score 17):

With dynamic provisioning, you shouldn't have to create PVs and PVCs separately. In Kubernetes 1.6+, there are default provisioners for GKE and some other cloud environments, which should let you just create a PVC and have it automatically provision a PV and an underlying Persistent Disk for you.

For more on dynamic provisioning, see:

https://kubernetes.io/blog/2017/03/dynamic-provisioning-and-storage-classes-kubernetes/

Answer (score 17):

Had the same issue but it was another reason that's why I am sharing it here to help community.

If you have deleted `PersistentVolumeClaim` and then re-create it again with the same definition, it will be Pending forever, why?

`persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy` is `Retain` by default in `PersistentVolume`. In case we have deleted `PersistentVolumeClaim`, the `PersistentVolume` still exists and the volume is considered released. But it is not yet available for another claim because the previous claimant's data remains on the volume.
so you need to manually reclaim the volume with the following steps:

1. Delete the PersistentVolume (associated underlying storage asset/resource like EBS, GCE PD, Azure Disk, ...etc will NOT be deleted, still exists)
2. (Optional) Manually clean up the data on the associated storage asset accordingly
3. (Optional) Manually delete the associated storage asset (EBS, GCE PD, Azure Disk, ...etc)

If you still need the same data, you may skip cleaning and deleting associated storage asset (step 2 and 3 above), so just simply re-create a new `PersistentVolume` with same storage asset definition then you should be good to create `PersistentVolumeClaim` again.

One last thing to mention, `Retain` is not the only option for `persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy`, below are some other options that you may need to use or try based on use-case scenarios:

**Recycle**: performs a basic scrub on the volume (e.g., `rm -rf //*`) - makes it available again for a new claim. Only `NFS` and `HostPath` support recycling.

**Delete**: Associated storage asset such as `AWS EBS, GCE PD, Azure Disk, or OpenStack Cinder...etc` volume is deleted

For more information, please check [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#:%7E:text=Retain,data%20remains%20on%20the%20volume.).

Still need more clarification or have any questions, please don't hesitate to leave a comment and I will be more than happy to clarify and assist.

Comment: Does just deleting the data from PV will resolve this issue? I can not delete PV and create new PV due to some restrictions. But as i have deleted PVC, I am not able to create a new one and its showing in pending status

Comment: @iRunner   you don't have to delete data itself but you still have to delete PV (logical volume not actual data) - (don't worry as associated underlying storage will NOT be deleted if you decide to delete PV)

Comment: @MuhammadSoliman if i don't have access to the PV, because you need cluster-admin rights to delete, what should be done then?. The behaviour i am looking for is; if i delete the pvc then i want to make the pv available again for another claim. Or do you suggest to just delete the pod and leave the pvc intact so it can be reused in the pod again?

Comment: What if I deleted the namespace that the sc/pv/pvc was defined already? And run scripts again for secret and volume yaml file? My situation is KinD cluster, azure file share. Same scripts work for aks cluster

Answer (score 13):

If you're using Microk8s, you have to enable storage before you can start a PersistentVolumeClaim successfully.

Just do:

```
microk8s.enable storage
```

You'll need to delete your deployment and start again.

You may also need to manually delete the "pending" PersistentVolumeClaims because I found that uninstalling the Helm chart which created them didn't clear the PVCs out.

You can do this by first finding a list of names:

```
kubectl get pvc --all-namespaces
```

then deleting each name with:

```
kubectl delete pvc name1 name2 etc...
```

Once storage is enabled, reapplying your deployment should get things going.

Comment: Worked like a charm in microk8s/ubuntu 19.10

Comment: Worked for me with microk8s on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Be careful to not delete other pvcs, the first comment would show all existing pvc from all process.

Comment: Omg this response is just top all over the internet! Thanks bro, moved me forward

Answer (score 8):

I was facing the same problem, and realise that k8s actually does a just-in-time provision, i.e.

- When a pvc is created, it stays in PENDING state, and no corresponding pv is created.
- The pvc & pv (EBS volume) are created only after you have created a deployment which uses the pvc.

I am using EKS with kubernetes version `1.16` and the behaviour is controlled by [StorageClass Volume Binding Mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#volume-binding-mode).

Answer (score 2):

When you want to bind manually a PVC to a PV with an existing disk, the `storageClassName` should not be specified... but... the cloud provider has set by default the "standard" StorageClass making it always entered whatever you try when patching the PVC/PV.

You can check your provider set it as default when doing `kubectl get storageclass` (it will be written "(default")).

To fix this the best is to get your existing StorageClass YAML and add this annotation:

```
  annotations:
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "false"
```

Apply and good :)

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem. My PersistentVolumeClaim yaml was originally as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc
spec:
  storageClassName: “”
  accessModes:
    – ReadWriteOnce 
  volumeName: pv
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

and my pvc status was:

[image]

after remove **volumeName** :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc
spec:
  storageClassName: “”
  accessModes:
    – ReadWriteOnce 
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

[image]

Comment: OP's manifest does not have the `.spec.volumeName` field.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this behaviour in `microk8s` 1.14.1 when two `PersistentVolume`s have the same value for `spec/hostPath/path`, e.g.

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pv-name
  labels:
    type: local
    app: app
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/k8s-app-data"
```

It seems that microk8s is event-based (which isn't necessary on a one-node cluster) and throws away information about any failing operations resulting in unnecessary horrible feedback for almost all failures.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with helmchart of the apache airflow(stable), setting storageClass to azurefile helped. What you should do in such cases with the cloud providers? Just search for the storage classes that support the needed access mode. ReadWriteMany means that SIMULTANEOUSLY many processes will read and write to the storage. In this case(azure) it is azurefile.

```
path: /opt/airflow/logs

  ## configs for the logs PVC
  ##
  persistence:
    ## if a persistent volume is mounted at `logs.path`
    ##
    enabled: true

    ## the name of an existing PVC to use
    ##
    existingClaim: ""

    ## sub-path under `logs.persistence.existingClaim` to use
    ##
    subPath: ""

    ## the name of the StorageClass used by the PVC
    ##
    ## NOTE:
    ## - if set to "", then `PersistentVolumeClaim/spec.storageClassName` is omitted
    ## - if set to "-", then `PersistentVolumeClaim/spec.storageClassName` is set to ""
    ##
    storageClass: "azurefile"

    ## the access mode of the PVC
    ##
    ## WARNING:
    ## - must be: `ReadWriteMany`
    ##
    ## NOTE:
    ## - different StorageClass support different access modes:
    ##   https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes
    ##
    accessMode: ReadWriteMany

    ## the size of PVC to request
    ##
    size: 1Gi
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Wish the airflow documentation was more elaborate

Answer (score 1):

Am using microk8s

Fixed the problem by running the commands below

```
systemctl start open-iscsi.service
```

(had open-iscsi installed earlier using `apt install open-iscsi` but had not started it)

Then enabled storage as follows

```
microk8s.enable storage
```

Then, deleted the Stateful Sets and the pending Persistence Volume Claims from Lens so  I can start over.

Worked well after that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had overlooked `accessModes` which were different between PV (RWM) and PVC (RWO).

Once I fixed this mistake the PVC was able to bind to the PV, as expected.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue in which the PersistentVolumeClaim was in Pending Phase indefinitely, I tried providing the storageClassName as 'default' in PersistentVolume just like I did for PersistentVolumeClaim but it did not fix this issue.

I made one change in my persistentvolume.yml and moved the PersistentVolumeClaim config on top of the file and then PersistentVolume as the second config in the yml file. It has fixed that issue.

We need to make sure that PersistentVolumeClaim is created first and the PersistentVolume is created afterwards to resolve this 'Pending' phase issue.

I am posting this answer after testing it for a few times, hoping that it might help someone struggling with it.

Comment: I found that the overly long Pending phase is not caused by the creation order of the two components. I tried as you suggested and it assigned it about 2 seconds faster. The root cause in my case was to replace ReadWriteMany with ReadWriteOnce when using storageClassName: storage

Answer (score -4):

Make sure your VM also has enough disk space.